# Recurso literario para convertir "Me explico" en "Mesplico"

Tags: coloquialismos

Me sale naturalmente juntar ambas palabras.
¿Existe algun recurso literario que valide esta forma de expresion?

"Me explico" -> "Mesplico"

Comment: Almost, but not quite http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinalefa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo diría que es más una elisión que una sinalefa, pero además se cambia la "x" por "s". Como figura retórica, entrecomillada o en letra cursiva, para indicar que alguien pronuncia de esta forma "me explico", cabe cualquier "atentado lingüístico", pero en otro caso es inaceptable en un escrito formal.

En otro caso, podría extenderse este recurso a cualquier parte del texto, y al final nos ocurriría como al que imaginó hacer una "[Sensilla ortografia para ke todo sea mas fasil](http://desdeelparedon.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/perez-reverte-sensilla-ortografia-para.html)": que lo escribes no se parezca en nada al español.

Answer (score 1):

En el habla común relajada pueden ser aceptables -o al menos tolerables- algunas pronunciaciones incorrectas  ("explicar"=> "esplicar", "peleé" => "pelié",  "reloj" => "reló" ). Pero, incluso cuando uno puede permitirse hablar así, nunca escribirá así, a menos que sea por ignorancia, o como recurso literario (por ejemplo, el [Martín Fierro](http://martinfierro.org/30.htm)).